# How to find and replace text strings in multiple files using VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript, replace

I have a basic question about a simple VBScript. My goal is to find a replace multiple text strings in multiple files.  (The 21 text strings to replace are the same across files.)  The file names have about 12 prefixes and then will have numbers 1 to 200 at the end.  The code I am using for just one of the strings in one of the files is as follows.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\filename_XX.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "Test 1", "Test 2")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\filename_XX.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewText
objFile.Close
```

I just want to loop over the file names and possibly loop over the search strings.  Could a For...Next loop accomplish this?  Can I refer to the number of the for loop in the filename object?

I have seen a response about searching over subfolders, but I think it is more sophisticated than what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in the same directory and all have a filename like `prefix_##.txt` you could do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set prefixes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
prefixes.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'make dictionary lookups case-insensitive
prefixes.Add "prefix1", True
prefixes.Add "prefix2", True
'...

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\basefolder").Files
  If InStr(f.Name, "_") > 0 Then
    If prefixes.Exists(Split(f.Name, "_")(0)) Then
      text = fso.OpenTextFile(f.FullName).ReadAll
      text = Replace(text, "Test 1", "Test 2")
      fso.OpenTextFile(f.FullName, 2).Write text
    End If
  End If
Next
```

If you want to use the number part of the file name, you have to extract it from the file name, e.g. like this:

```
num = Split(fso.GetBaseName(f.Name), "_")(1)
```

If your files are not all in the same directory you'll need to recurse into subfolders. Also, if you have file names like `prefix_##somethingelse.txt` or `prefix_##.otherextension`, you'll have to add further checks to exclude them from processing.