# Replace characters in multiplis files txt

Tags: vbscript

Hello i am looking for a code for change characters on all Text File inside one folder `C:\prueba`

Now i can change one file, but i dont know how to change the code for open all `*.txt`, read, change and close.

For now this is my code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\prueba\BCNtest.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strText = Replace(strText, "ª", "")
strText = Replace(strText, "º", "")
strText = Replace(strText, "/", "")
strText = Replace(strText, "-", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\prueba\BCNtest.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strText

objFile.Close
```

all files start by `BCN*.txt`....

i tried with "`.txt`" and "`BCN.txt`" but of course this not worked :D

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424568/how-to-find-and-replace-text-strings-in-multiple-files-using-visual-basic

Comment: yes, sorry i read that my last post was delete, and i follow the instruction of the admin for create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this code for select the file that i want to open.. But later i dont know how to change the character to this file selected.

```
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE> 
<script>FILE.click();new 
ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).
WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
sFileSelected = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
wscript.echo sFileSelected


Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("what put here?", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strText = Replace(strText, "ª", "")
strText = Replace(strText, "º", "")
strText = Replace(strText, "/", "")
strText = Replace(strText, "-", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("what put here?", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strText

objFile.Close
```